# HsqlException: type not found or user lacks privilege: NUMBER

Tags: java, hsqldb

I'm using hsql 2.3.3. According to [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#coc_compatibility_oracle) I can fix this either by adding additional statement to the sql

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE
```

or by adding property to the url

```
url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;sql.syntax_ora=true
```

First one fixes the issue for me (so this is root cause of it), but I would like to use second one as it looks more generalized for me. But url property does't do the trick. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The URL property works only if you create a new database with the connection property. The new database will then include the SQL statement and run it automatically at each startup.